# Wrapping a type, but preserving its behavior regarding function overloads?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

I have a mechanism that uses function overloads to decompose a type into primitives. Here is a sample of the mechanism:

```
template <typename M, typename T> void process(M&, T&);

template <typename M, typename T>
void process_impl(M& m, const T& t) {
  m.write(t);
}
template <typename M, typename T>
void process_impl(M& m, const std::vector<T>& v) {
  for (const auto& t: v) {
    process(m, t);
  }
}

template <typename M, typename T>
void process(M& m, const T& t) {
  process_impl(m, t);
}
```

The use case is to feed a type to `process()`, which will decompose it into simple types using the overloads of `process_impl()`. In order to customize the behavior of `process()` for a specific type, simply overload `process()`:

```
struct media {
  template <typename T> void write(const T& t) { std::cout << t << std::endl; }
};
void process(media& m, const std::string& s) {
  process(m, s.size());
}
```

This code:

```
media m;
process(m, std::vector<std::string>{"1", "22"});
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
```

Now, I want to wrap `media` in a class, such that I can further tweak the behavior of `process()` for my wrapper structure, but I want to preserve the initial behavior of `process()` regarding `media`:

```
template <typename M>
struct debug_media {
  template <typename T> void write(const T& t) { m.write(t); }

  M m;
};
template <typename M, typename T>
void process(debug_media<M>& d, const T& t) {
  std::cout << "debug: ";
  process(d.m, t);
}
```

Ideally, I want the output to be:

```
debug: 1
debug: 2
```

But that is not the case, since the overload for `debug_media` is used only once, for the first invocation; afterward, the overloads of `process()` that accept a `media` are used, not the one with `debug_media<media>`.

I cannot have inheritance between `media` and `debug_media`. Is it possible to preserve the behavior of both overloads?

I have put sample code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/wP8ROU).

Comment: Why can't you simply define `debug_media::write` as `{ cout << "debug\n"; m.write(t);}`

Comment: @sbabbi Because I do not want to have my specific behavior triggered each time `write()` is invoked; for example, I can have multiple calls to `write()` within a single implementation of `process_impl()`.

Comment: @sbabbi Also, I cannot have a state within `debug_media` because there can be recursive calls to `process()`.

Comment: What is the template parameter `M` in `debug_media` used for?

Comment: @JasonR In this case, it is how the media type is specified; there is an error in the sample: attribute `debug_media::m` is of type `M`, not explicitely `media`; I'll update the example

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extra overload:

```
template <typename M, typename T> void process(debug_media<M>& d, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for(const auto& t : v) {
        process(d, t);
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/xajtgk)

Comment: The problems are that 1/ I have a significant set of overloads, so re-implementing all of them will be painful; and even so 2/ how do I detect when a new overload will eventually be implemented?